# Amazon S3 public access price?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket, which has several audio files opened for public access. I have the audio file URL like https://bucket_name.s3.aws_url.com/folder_name/audio_file.mp3.

The URL is accessible through my app. Does it cost me any additional charge? if yes, is there any better way to restrict this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: With S3, you pay for outgoing data, among other things https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Thank you for the price URL. As far I understand that this data transfer came under the Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To the Internet. Is there any better way to limit the additional price?

Comment: Not sure what is it you are asking. It's a pay-as-you-go model. If you want to pay less, use less.

Comment: What I ask is that if I can transfer the data through my server (I have an Ec2 instance) rather than a direct URL, can it make any difference?

Comment: **$0.010 per GB - regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB 64.456 GB $0.64**. Does this additional charge come from s3 outgoing data?

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict this"?

Comment: The s3 bucket is set to public access. I presume users access these bucket files only through the app. Is there any better way to make it under control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Data Transfer cost applies to *any* AWS Service.

Therefore, a user downloading a file from Amazon S3 would incur the same cost as downloading that file from an Amazon EC2 instance.

If you wish to avoid unauthorised access to the file (eg users who try to access the object but are not actual users of your app), then you can implement [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which are time-limited URLs generated by your application. Basically, keep the object private in S3, and when your back-end wishes to provide a user access to the object it can generate the pre-signed URL that allows the user to access the private object.